# How to process request headers in Koa.js?

Tags: node.js, content-type, koa.js, ctx

How to accept request content-type of `application/vnd.api+json` and reject anything else?

Also how can I access the `x-api-key` value using Koa.js ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: if (!ctx.accepts('application/vnd.api+json')) {        
        ctx.throw(406, 'unsupported content-type'); } // but not getting status 406 in Postman. For x-api-key cannot find any documentation

Comment: Include a full, reproducible script in your question if you need help!

Comment: I also had tried if (ctx.is(application/vnd.api+json) { .. } as describe here https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/request.md and that didn't work for me so I used a simple comparison if (ctx.request.type=='application/vnd.api+json') { .. }

Answer (score 24):

To get the header: `ctx.get('x-api-key');`

Answer (score 8):

This is my attempt to the first part of the question, content negotiation:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

//const dataAPI = require('../models/traffic');

router.get('/locations/:geohash/traffic/last-hour', (ctx, next) => {    
    // some code for validating geohash goes here ...

    if (ctx.request.type=='application/vnd.api+json') {        
        //ctx.body = dataAPI.getTrafficData(ctx.params.geohash, 'hours', 1);
        ctx.body = { status: "success" };
        ctx.type = "application/vnd.api+json";
        next();
    }
    else {
       ctx.throw(406, 'unsupported content-type');
       // actual error will be in JSON API 1.0 format
    }
});
```

I am getting status `406 Not Acceptable` and `unsupported content-type` in Postman when I submit the value for Content-Type in Postman anything that is not application/vnd.api+json. Otherwise, I get station `200 OK` and `{ "status": "success"` in the body.

**Edited**

Haven't found a better to this but below is a quick and dirty way to extract the value of `x-api-key`. It works for my purpose:

```
var key = ctx.request.headers['x-api-key']
```